# Modelling a skewed, 10-point Satisfaction variable

Tags: logistic, multiple-regression, residuals, normality-assumption, ordered-logit

I am trying to replicate and hopefully improve on an analysis done in a study to find determinants of patient satisfaction after shoulder surgery.  Satisfaction is heavily skewed (with over 60% of patients responding 10)  The original study ran a multiple linear regression on satisfaction with a handful of predictors.  The residuals are just as skewed as the satisfaction variable itself, and no transformations I've tried have helped, probably because the variable is discrete (could argue ordinal or numerical).

My other thoughts have been to use ordinal regression on the full 10-level scale, or lump responses together into two or more groups for binary (say 10 vs not 10) or multinomial logistic regression.  The former seems to suffer from decreased interpretability and the later seems to lose information that might be important.

Am I missing any ideas/techniques?  How do I choose between these various evils?

Thanks in advance for any responses!

Comment: "*the later seems to lose information that might be important*" - are you able to clairfy how multinomial logistic regression is losing important information?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear.
Ordinal regression = less convenient interpretation,
Lumping satisfaction values together = lost information